# Oracle 11g R2 installation on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, ubuntu

I have installed Oracle 11g R2 on ubuntu 14.04 LTS.
On terminal I wrote following to start oracle:

```
sudo service oracle-xe start
```

on pressing enter, got following output :

```
" Starting Oracle Net Listener.
  touch: cannot touch '/var/lock/subsys/listener' : No such file or directory
  Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance.
  Failed to start Oracle Net Listener using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/tnslsnr
  and Oracle Express Database using /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/bin/sqlplus. "
```

What should I do now.

Comment: have you installed oracle 11gR2 correctly like the below link i mean the steps. because you might have missed something. **http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.in/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html**

Answer (score 2):

try these commands on terminal :

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/lock/subsys

sudo chmod -R 777 /var/lock/subsys
```

Comment: You don't really need `chmod` as the init script is supposed to be run by `root`.